# mgwt: get ios look and feel

Tags: cordova, gwt, mgwt

I am creating a phonegap app with gwt phonegap. How can I create the iPhone Look and Feel?

Right now, I have en entry im my gwt.xml-file:

```
<inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.theme.platform.Platform" />
```

I am testing the app using the Phonegap-Emulator. Altough the functionality works as expected, the app doesnt have the iPhone look.

Do I need to use certain Widgets to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I suggest you edit the title since this is an mgwt question that has nothing to do with gwtphonegap.

When you say that you use the 'Phonegap-Emulator' I assume that you mean something like [Ripple](http://emulate.phonegap.com/), and not the iOS Simulator (which would be used by `cordova emulate ios`)

In the `Platform.gwt.xml`, the OS is determined via the user agent:

```
<define-property name="mgwt.os" values="android, ios" />
<property-provider name="mgwt.os"><![CDATA[
    // Detect mgwt.os from user agent.
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf("iphone") != -1 || ua.indexOf("ipod") != -1) {
        // iphone and ipod.
        return "ios";
    } else if (ua.indexOf("ipad") != -1) {
        // ipad.
        return "ios";
    } else if (ua.indexOf("android") != -1) {
        return "android";  
    }
    return "ios";
]]></property-provider>
```

The `mgwt.os` property is then used to determine the correct Appearance for your widgets, for example in `Button.gwt.xml`:

```
<replace-with class="com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.theme.platform.button.ButtonIOSAppearance">
    <when-type-is class="com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.button.ButtonAppearance" />
<when-property-is name="mgwt.os" value="ios" />
    </replace-with>
```

To answer your question, make sure that the user agent in your emulator contains the string "iphone" or "ios", or, simply set the OS property to iOS by adding

```
<set-property name="mgwt.os" value="ios" />
```

to your gwt.xml.